# How to manage certfile renew in golang with gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a mini gin micro service that need https. But sometimes, my certfile is renewed with certbot but I don't know when, and my gin micro service is still using the old cert.

```
func Run() {
    fmt.Println("begin")
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(cors.Default())
    r.POST("getLieu/", getAdr)
    r.GET("lucky/", Lucky)

    r.RunTLS((":8083"),"/etc/letsencrypt/live/toto.fr/fullchain.pem","/etc/letsencrypt/live/toto.fr/privkey.pem") // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

How can i tell my gin program to check if the cert have changed or not?

Comment: Not familiar with Gin but presumably you can specify the tls.Config somehow. Use [the GetCertificate field](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config.GetCertificate) to load the certificate on demand.

Comment: https://github.com/dyson/certman and https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You restart it periodically.

Analogue example, nginx sits in front of your gin program:

- Certs are valid for 3 months
- Every month a `certbot renew` cronjob or systemd timer is ran
- Every week nginx is restarted

The same happens with your gin program. You restart the gin program (/service) every week.

Extra points: [graceful shutdown](https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples/blob/master/graceful-shutdown/graceful-shutdown/server.go)

Answer (score 0):

I think this package will help.

https://github.com/caddyserver/certmagic

Also give this a view: https://www.dotconferences.com/2016/10/matthew-holt-go-with-acme

The ACME (Automated Certificate Management Environment) is going to be a good feature to use for your kind of question I think!